# How to get wav file volume level?

Tags: c++, audio, wav, analysis

I need something like a class or function or whatever that can take a wav file as an input an give me the vloums value.
if something like this is not Exist, how should I get those values ?
is there any way at all ?

I got the frequencies, I want the Volume.
by the way Im coding in C++.
Thank u for ur answers.

explanation: by volume I mean sound intensity and amplitude.

Comment: Do you know something about [libbass](http://www.un4seen.com/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "the volume"? The peak loudness? Some kind of average? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Volume is related to a measurable quantity : Root Mean Square (RMS).  Once you gain access to the audio curve RMS can be calculated for a chosen audio buffer size (entire clip or some portion)  Conceptually, you simply walk across a set of samples (each entry of a buffer) where for example the audio curve values may vary from -1 to +1 and you square each value then add to a running total then take the square root of this total. RMS is just the average value of the source values.  Short of rolling your own algorithm checkout implementations : [ReplayGain](http://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Replay_Gain)

Answer (score 0):

Considering http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/ I dont think volume information can be retrieved from the wav file itself. Also, generally, "volume" is subject to the hardware playing the wav file and not the wav file itself if im not mistaken.

Comment: by volume I mean sound intensity and amplitude.